# Connecting to mongolab db in the shell, but not in Robomongo

Tags: mongodb, mlab, robo3t

I am trying to connect to a MongoLab DB using the credentials and user I set up.  I chose the AWS instance using the 500mb of storage (the free Sandbox version).  It said it was 3.0.x for Mongo (showing 3.0.9 in MongoLab).

On my environment I am running `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1`

Using the command:

```
mongo ds011111.mongolab.com:11111/mydbname -u dbname -p dbpass
```

in the shell, I am able to connect to the DB just fine.  However, when trying to connect through Robomongo, I am not.  I am using the same username, password, database name, host and port.  When I run the test, it connects to the host and port just fine, but it says Authorization Fails (this should not be, as I was just authorized to connect in the shell).

What is going?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. Just RoboMongo 0.8.x does not support Mongo 3.0+. You can download [0.9 RC4](http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-rc4/).